# (Android) Rendering errors when the theme is changed to Material.light

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-theme

Hi I was following some android tutorials in youtube, and in the preview of the design tab, I get the following errors

[image]

However, the problem is I didn't get any of these errors in the theme 'Apptheme'. But when I changed the theme to Material.light suddenly these errors appeared.

Here is my content_main.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="234dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:text="Hi"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is my styles.xml code.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name = "coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Support.CoordinatorLayout</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

What is the possible reason why I get these problems when I change my theme to Material.light?